# How to export half a million records from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've a table with around 500,000 records. I need all records to be exported in excel. When I query I'm not able to get all as I was said as `Out Of memory`

Table doesn't have any primary key/Index.

Is there any way to extract?

Comment: How are you extracting?

Comment: simple......`select * from table`

Comment: try saving a spool file into .csv format, and select * from table, 
once done you can do format text to column using excel , that should help

Comment: What is out of memory? How _exactly_ are you exporting it? SQL Developer? PL/SQL Developer? Toad? SQL*Plus? `UTL_FILE`? Java? ow big is the table? 500,000 rows could be less than 5MB!

Comment: @Ben `pl/sql developer`

Answer (score 0):

it would be very easy in to write file output form sqlplus . 
mycsv.sql:

```
SET DEFINE OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET PAGESIZE 10000
SET ARRAYSIZE 5000
REM SET HEAD OFF
SET LINE 500
spool /tmp/mycsvfile.csv;
select * from MY_table;
spool off;
exit;
```

and from Linux prompt you can run like

```
$> sqlplus username/password @/tmp/mycsv.sql
```

Comment: ..is it same for pl/sql too??